# Why is my code in python not giving an output at all?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, debugging, while-loop

I wrote some code in python to see how many times one number can be divided by a number, until it gets a value of one.

```
counter_var = 1
quotient = num1/num2

if quotient<1:
    print('1 time')
else:
    while quotient >= 1:
        quotient = num1/num2
        counter_var =  counter_var + 1
    print(counter_var)
```

It is not ending the process but neither is it giving any output.

Comment: No matter how many times you divide `num1` by `num2`, the result is always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not changing the value of quotient in the while loop. it remains constant.
instead of **quotient = num1/num2** it should be **quotient /= num2** if I understand your problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

well to start, you're missing assignment to numbers,
in the case of num1>num2 , you will be entering an endless while loop and hence you will never get to the  `print(counter_var)` snippet

Answer (score 0):

I did a slight change to your code, since you are always defining the quotient as the initial numbers. Instead, divide your quotient against the num2.

```
counter_var = 1
quotient = num1/num2

if quotient<1:
    print('1 time')
else:
    quotient = num1/num2
    while quotient >= 1:
        quotient = quotient/num2
        counter_var =  counter_var + 1
    print(counter_var)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us breakdown your code with an examples:

## section 1: all good code

```
counter_var = 1
quotient = num1/num2

if quotient<1:
    print('1 time')
else:
```

## section 2: problem code

```
    while quotient >= 1:
        quotient = num1/num2
        counter_var =  counter_var + 1
    print(counter_var)
```

Let us take an example where

## num1 = 20

## num2 = 4

It goes through section 1. All is good. The value of `quotient` is `5.0`. So it goes into while statement. The `quotient` will always remain `5.0`.

What do you think will be the result of the next calculation? You didn't change the value of `num1` and `num2` so it will continue to be `5.0`. And so it goes into an endless loop.

If you want to change the code, you have to figure out how to change the value of `num1` so it can divide further.

Hope this helps you debug your code to get to the right answer. I will leave you to figure out how to fix this.

Hint: any number divided by itself will continue to remain at 1. You man want to look at your while loop and make a small change. Should it be `>=` ?

Comment: I don't see that quotient would ever be 1.0 with num1 = 20 and num2 = 4. It starts 5.0, it stays 5.0. It is true that special care should be taken to avoid infinite loops when num1 = num2 = 1, but this answer doesn't accurately diagnose what's happening in the asker's code.

Answer (score 0):

you write a infinite loop ! for example if you take 1 as input of num1 and 1 also an input of num2 ! so quotient here take 1 !! so you stuck in infinite loop ! i don't  understand your program i mean what you wanna do ! you have to show me the problem first

Answer (score 0):

The value of quotient is not changing so the loop is going on forever. For example if quotient is 3, num1 is 18 and num2 is 6. The program will go into the else statement and then continue on to the while statement. It divides 18 by 6 and sets the value of quotient to 3 and increments counter_var by one. Than it goes back to the top of the loop and does the same thing since quotient is >= 1, and the value of quotient never changes which is causing the loop to go on forever.

Other problems:

Variable names should not have an underscore and should be camelCased meaning it should be counterVar.
Also you should have more descriptive names rather than num1 and num2.